# Definition of solvable group in Fraleigh book

Tags: group-theory, definition, solvable-groups

I have been using Fraleigh's book, A first course in abstract algebra
There is one thing I want you to ask whether the definition of solvable group in this book is right or not.

In my book, definition of Solvable group is as follows

> A group $G$ is solvable if it has a **composition series** $\{H_i\}$ such that all factor groups $H_{i+1}/H_i$ are Abelian.

But most of other book give quite different definition of solvable group. They define it :

> A group $G$ is solvable if it has a **subnormal seires** $\{H_i\}$ such that all factor groups $H_{i+1}/H_i$ are Abelian.

are these two definition equivalent?

Comment: A [composition series](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_series) is a type of subnormal series.

Comment: Yes but the infinite cyclic group is solvable but has no composition series. The definition you quote from Fraleigh's book is correct only when $G$ is finite. Even if you are only working with finite groups, you should still use the standard definition of solvable group. the same applies to nilpotent groups, which should be defined using central series. Incidentally, in the second definition, you can replace "subnormal series" by "normal series" if you want to, because that is equivalent.